# How to save and compare U-Boot environment and fw_env.config

Tags: u-boot, yocto

I'm using Yocto Dunfell and attempting to make use of Mender (https://mender.io) for OTA updates.  My problem is similar to the question posed in the Mender forum [here](https://hub.mender.io/t/error-in-u-boot-setup-boot-and-root-partitions-dont-match/855).

However, my question is related to the technique for troubleshooting instead of Mender.  The troubleshooting involves comparing the environment variables in U-Boot with those in /etc/fw_env.config.

I know how to boot to U-Boot and save the environment to MMC.  Where is this saved so I can compare the results when booting normally?

**Update 1**

In the u-boot command line, **saveenv** will save the environment.  My question is simply where is this saved so I can grab it later when I boot in normal mode?

Comment: If you know how to save the environment, why are you asking where it is saved? It should be saved where you saved it.

Comment: Is it saved to a file?

Comment: No idea. I guess it depends on how you save it.

Comment: The command is saveenv.  I just need to know where this is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveenv` command saves the environment to the location defined by u-boot configuration options. If you're saving it to a file (most likely scenario on the Pi), check the following options:

```
FAT_ENV_INTERFACE
FAT_ENV_DEVICE_AND_PART
FAT_ENV_FILE
```

The default filename is `uboot.env`, so you may as well start by looking for that file.